# Why does Adobe Reader 9 report that a document could not be printed because there were no pages?

Tags: printer, printing, adobe-reader

When I try to print a PDF I get a message box that says "the document could not be printed". I then get another message box that says "there were no pages selected to print". The sender could print it. Other users on same computer are unable to print their docs but I can print from Word.

Comment: What about other PDF readers, such as [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) or [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/landing_chrome.html?hl=en)?

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem, and the built-in uninstall program wouldn't let me delete/re-install Adobe Reader.
Wound up downloading "Revo Un-installer" from download.com (CNET) and fully deleting Adobe Reader.  After a complete delete and system restart I went back to adobe.com re downloaded 9.3.3 Reader and installed...  Works great now.

Best of Luck hope this helps.

Comment: I had same problem with Reader 10.0.1 on Win XP Pro. +1 for uninstall/reinstall suggestion, this worked, though I didn't need to use a 3rd party uninstaller. I also deleted the `%appdata%\Application Data\Adobe` and `%appdata%\Local Settings\Adobe` folders and ran CCleaner for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

I was baffled by this problem too before stumbled upon a work around.

With the targeted PDF file opened in Adobe Reader, click "print".  In the printer dialog window, I have "Adobe PDF" listed as a possible selection for available printers.  Choosing that and clicking print would bring up another window to let you type in the file name and location for the new PDF file to be saved.  I can then print the newly created PDF file with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

One user affected here.
Printing on another network printer was running fine.
So I deleted the affected network printer from the local connections then reinstalled it - working fine after.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a bug in a version of Abode Reader (but I'm sure they fixed it long ago) where you could not print files if the full path name was extremely long (which they can be if they are saved to the temporary files folder).

Saving the files to a folder with a short path name resolved the issue. (Found this out when we have a customer with dozens of pdfs (send to them via email) saved to their desktop, as  'that is the one way I can print them'.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't print because no page was selected. Noticed an update icon in my task bar for Adobe Reader and installed the update. Now everything works.

I'm running version 9.4.1 so check to see if an update fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Acrobat Pro 9.5.1
Fix for me was:
In Print dialog box - 
choose to only print 'document'
NOT 'Document & Markups'

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to print the PDF from a different PDF reader like [PDF-Xchange](http://www.docu-track.com/home/prod_user/PDF-XChange_Tools/pdfx_viewer).